# Android NDK non-deterministic Socket connect() time out

Tags: android, c, sockets, android-ndk

I have problems with client/server application that is part of a bigger system for distributed computing. The clients are Android devices that run a native Android NDK application written in C. At some point the clients send registration messages to the server application, which is also written in C and runs on a windows machine.

The weird thing is, right after installing the Android application on the device everything works fine. However, after a while the Socket problem starts. All `connect()` function calls end with a time out on the client side. The error is not deterministic and occurs at different points in time. To make it work again, I have to uninstall the application in Android manually and reinstall it. After that I works for some time and then the error starts again. The same C code is used on clients that run on normal windows PCs and there the problem does not occur.

The network connection is fine and I checked, if the server ports are open and reachable with the Simple Socket Tester app from the client device. I also gave Android the permission for Internet use and the parameters of the `connect()` call are correct.

EDIT:

Sorry for the missing code. I thought the error is obvious and based on the different platforms, since it works on windows and I am not that experienced in Android NDK. Here is the code:

```
int pi_connect(SOCKET s, const SOCKADDR *name, int namelen) 
{

    int result = connect(s, name, namelen);

    if (result < 0) {
        ALOG("Socket connecting error!");

        return -1;
    }

    return result;
}

SOCKET pi_socket(int af, int type, int protocol) {

    SOCKET returnSocket = socket(af, type, protocol);
    int yes = 1;
    if (setsockopt(returnSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Server-setsockopt() error!");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (returnSocket < 0) {
        ALOG("Socket creation error!");

        return -1;
    }

    return returnSocket;
}

SOCKET setupSendSocket(u_long host, int hostPort) {
    SOCKET sendingSocket;
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;

    sendingSocket = pi_socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(hostPort);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = host;

    long rc = pi_connect(sendingSocket, (SOCKADDR*) &addr, sizeof(SOCKADDR));
    if (rc < 0) {
        return 0;
    } 
    return sendingSocket;
}

void requestOwnIP() {

    SOCKET connectedIPSocket = setupSendSocket(inet_addr(brokerIP), 34123);

    if(connectedIPSocket==0)
        return;

    sendBHeartbeatMessage(connectedIPSocket);

    myIP = receiveBIPMessage(connectedIPSocket);

    pi_closesocket(connectedIPSocket);
}
```

The `requestOwnIP()` function is called in the main function of the NDK application.

EDIT 2 (some new remarks): After rebooting the device, the `connect()` is successful again and the system works for some time. Is there something stored in the process table of the operating system, that can cause this problem? I first though that it could be a high amount of sockets that are in the `time_wait` state, but I added SO_REUSEADDR and the problem is still occurring.

I would really appreciate some help. Thank you in advance!

Regards
Dominik

Comment: The problem is somewhere in the code you won't show us. Questions like these without code are off-topic.

Comment: Sorry for that. I added the code. Thank you!

Comment: What if instead of reinstall you simply force stop the app? Or clear data?

Comment: Stopping does not help as well as clearing the data. In fact, reinstalling the applications via Android Studio does not help. Only manually uninstalling (in the Android app settings) helps, after the error occurs for the first time.